# jQuery click not working on appended dom

Tags: jquery

I appended some div like this :

```
var to = "Some content"
$("#key").append("<div class=\"cont\">"+to+"  <span ded="+ lastid +" class=\"\contspan\">X</span></div>  ");
```

Then i tried to bind a click on event on the div with class `cont` by doing this :

```
$('.cont').delegate('div', 'click', function() {
    $("#logger").html("click")
});
```

But this doesnt works ?
Where have i been going wrong ?

**EDIT**:
I tried to place a bacground color to the class `cont` And the color is there to show that class id added fine

Comment: Escape orgies are aweful. Please make use of both `'` and `"` quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't using delegate quite right, try this:

```
$('#key').delegate('div.cont', 'click', function() {
    //var text1 = $(this).attr("ded");
    $("#logger").html("click")
});
```

You call the delegate method on the element that isn't going to change ('#key') and then pass it the selector for the dynamic element ('div.cont') as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .live() function instead of delegate.

```
$('.cont').live('click', function() {
    // var text1 = $(this).attr("ded");
    $("#logger").html("click");
}
```

Comment: Why would you use live rather than delegate?

Comment: I personally prefer live and have a good experience when I need to register events for elements that have not been created yet. It's usage matches the scenario that @kritya presented. Sure, delegate can be used in the same way, but I would say that it is a matter of preference.

Comment: Fair enough, although I think delegate is slightly more efficient as the events don't have bubble up as far as they do with live. I didn't down vote you btw as your answer would work.

Comment: @Richard I agree that delegate has some advantages, especially as you mentioned there is not bubble up, however, I still did not have issue with bubble up, but am keeping delegate in my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `<div>` in your .cont there

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/1cbbd.php

```
<div id="key"> 

</div> 
<div id="logger"> 
</div> 
<script> 
var to = "Some content"; 
var lastid = "test"; 
$("#key").append("<div class='cont'>"+to+"<span ded='"+ lastid +"' class='contspan'>X</span></div> "); 
$('.cont').delegate('span', 'click', function() { 
    //var text1 = $(this).attr("ded"); 
    $("#logger").html("click") 
}); 
</script>
```